# Show Image when click a button

Tags: java, image, swing, drawable

I have a really short and simple cuestion.

What must Y type on *.java file to show a png file on screen when I click on a button.

I've been searching and trying with intents and many otrher ways but I've not found the answer.

Thanks

Comment: So what *exactly* have you tried (besides coming here and asking us to spoon feed the code to you)?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "on screen"? In a window? On its own? Have you got anything of the sort already? Generally speaking, you can use the ImageIO class to read from a PNG file into a BufferedImage:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("image.png"));
```

Then the quickest way is probably to attach the image to a label using ImageIcon:

```
JLabel imgLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
```

You can then add `imgLabel` to a JFrame or similar which you can then display.

Comment: First of all thank for your quickly answer. Probably I have not explained my problem enough so I am going to try again.

I mean I want to show a png file (which is on drawable folder)  in a new window on full screen when the user click on a button prepared for that.

I understand your answer but, how do you specify that this must happend when the user click on the button.

I supposed that some kind of "clickonlistener" must work but I have not been able to make it work correctly.

I have prepared the layout on the XML file and works fine but without action.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). The sections on `How to Write an Action Listener` or `How to Use Icons` would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: I just want to thank your help. I have never wanted nobody spoon feed the code to me.